# Why it's wrong to define a string like that in C (with regards to memory)?

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory

The address of local variables is from high to low. Since one way to define a string in C is to define a char pointer, I defined a char pointer and initialized it to &a-4, so it should point to 4 bytes below the int a in memory. Then I used scanf() with "%4s" to restrain it from reading only 4 charactors at most. If I scan a string, the 4 charactors should be saved into the address &a-4, &a-3, &a-2, &a-1 respectively in memory.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    char *string =  &a - 4;
    
    scanf("%4s", string);
    printf("%s", string);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[The result of running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf0b7.png)

But it's wrong just like that. What's the reason of it?

Comment: what you have here is undefined behavior. Dont try to reason about it. You make so many assumptions about memory layout, plus that subtraction is not 4 bytes. Even if you did manage to access 'spare' memory then call to scanf and printf would almost certainly reuse it

Comment: The '4 bytes below `a` in memory' (or, indeed, 16) don't belong to you, leave them alone.

Comment: The problem is that the language definition does not define the behaviour of `&a - 4` . There is no such definition as "take the memory address of `a` mapped to an integer and move backwards some bytes" as you seem to imagine.

Comment: Why it's wrong and doesn't work is because everything it depends on — the peculiar set of assumptions you've made — is *not* guaranteed.  These assumptions might once have been valid, on one system somewhere,  but less and less today, and evidently not on the machine you're using now.  Is there a reason you're trying to "allocate" memory in such a wildly nonportable way?  Was this an experiment?  Is there a reason you can't just declare `char string[4]`?

Comment: Thank yall!!! Maybe it's a undefined behavior, but when I corrected "&a - 4" to "&a - 1", it worked well surprisingly.. Why is that?

Comment: Maybe you are right Steven. Thank you! It was an experiment. I was just curious about it in C.

Comment: *Maybe it's a undefined behavior, but when I [changed...], it worked well surprisingly.. Why is that?* — Well, even a stopped clock is right twice a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The address of local variables is from high to low.

Are you sure about that?

> Since one way to define a string in C is to define a char pointer

Are you sure about that?

> I defined a char pointer and initialized it to &a-4, so it should point to 4 bytes below the int a in memory.

Are you sure about that?

---

So, taking each of these in turn...

C makes absolutely no guarantees about how variables are laid out in memory beyond the following:

- Array elements are laid out contiguously and successive elements have increasing addresses;
- `struct` members are laid out in the order they are declared and have increasing addresses; however, there may be unused padding bytes between members;

That’s it.  Beyond that, variable layout, byte order, etc. are all functions of the implementation. What works on your system may not work on mine.

In C, a *string* is a zero-terminated sequence of character values.  Strings are stored in arrays of character type.  A `char *` object is not a string.  A `char *` *may* point to the first character of a string, or it may point to the first of a sequence of characters that is not a string (not zero-terminated, or zero is counted as an in-band value), or it may point to a single `char` object that is not part of the larger sequence.

The value of the expression `&a` is the address of the first byte of `a` and its *type* is `int *`.  Pointer arithmetic is not done in terms of bytes, it’s done in terms of the size of the pointed-to type.  Adding 1 to a pointer expression yields a pointer to the next *object* of the pointed-to type, not the next byte.  Subtracting 4 from `&a` yields a pointer to the 4th `int` *object* prior to `a` (`4 * sizeof (int)` bytes).

You have not allocated an *array*.  The bytes at that address don’t belong to you; they may belong to part of the stack frame and writing to them may clobber something *important* such as the previous frame pointer, or the address of the next instruction to execute after the function returns, which is how a lot of malware works.

Your code invokes undefined behavior in multiple ways; it is erroneous, and you should not expect any specific result.

---

From the comments:

> In main, if you define a variable then define an array, their addresses are really always continuous in memory.

For *your particular system* that may indeed be the case, but it is not guaranteed to be true on all systems all the time.  The compiler is not required to lay out variables contiguously or in the same order that they were declared.

All your experiments tell you is how things work for *your* particular combination of compiler, OS, and hardware; they are not necessarily true everywhere else.  But since some of your experiments involve undefined behavior, the results of those experiments don’t have to be the same for different code or different builds of the same code.

> Sometimes, char* can be used to define a string like char* string="Hello world!". But it is a const string, and I just tried if it could be used to define a normal one.

Storage is still allocated for the string itself - the declaration above gives you something like this:

```
        +–––+      +–––+
string: |   | –––> |'H'|
        +–––+      +–––+
                   |'e'|
                   +–——+
                    ...
                   +–––+
                   |'d'|
                   +–––+
                   | 0 |
                   +–––+
```

The `string` variable points to the start of the string literal, but it is not the string itself; the actual string is the sequence of character values stored in an array that’s been allocated from *somewhere*.

The array that stores the string isn’t actually `const`; rather, the behavior on attempting to modify the contents of a string literal is *undefined*.  The compiler *may* store the contents of a string literal in read-only memory, but it doesn’t have to.  I’ve worked systems where modifying string literals "worked", and I’ve worked on systems where it caused a runtime error.

Best practice when declaring a pointer to a string literal is to declare the pointer as `const`:

```
const char *string = "Hello World";
```

That way if you attempt to modify the contents of the string like

```
string[0] = 'h';
```

the compiler will yell at you.

> when I changed it to &a-1, which should be right. This little experimental program worked well surprisingly

That’s the insidious thing about undefined behavior - one possible outcome is that it can work exactly as expected.  That is, until one day you make a change to some seemingly unrelated part of the program and it stops working completely.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is an experiment based on some evidences: 1, In main, if you define a variable then define an array, their addresses are really always continuous in memory. 2, Sometimes, char* can be used to define a string like char* string="Hello world!". But it is a const string, and I just tried if it could be used to define a normal one. 3, Ty for pointing out &a-4 was wrong, but when I changed it to &a-1, which should be right. This little experimental program worked well surprisingly..

Comment: @EternayLoveLyJoy: Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you. Your understandings are absolutely true. I've learned a lot. You are really knowledgeable John. The last question is how I can know one behavior is defined or not defined?

Comment: @EternayLoveLyJoy: See Annex J (specifically J.2) of the [C 2011 Online Draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for a complete list - it's not the latest official version of the language standard (that costs real money), but for this purpose it's good enough.  Remember that "undefined" just means that the compiler isn't required to issue any diagnostics (warnings, errors, whatever) or to handle the code in any particular way.  Your program may crash outright, or it may work exactly as expected, or it may corrupt data, or produce any other result.

Comment: I got what is a "undefined behavior". Thank you so much John!!!

Answer (score 2):

**Problem #1**

Say an `int` takes 4 bytes. And say `a` is at address `0x1000`, then the bytes of the integer are at `0x1000`, `0x1001`, `0x1002` and `0x1003`.

I don't know why you'd think they are at `0x0FFC`, `0x0FFD`, `0x0FFE` and `0x0FFF`, but that's completely wrong.

**Problem #2**

Next is the issue that you misunderstand how pointer subtraction and addition works.

Subtracting an integer amount from a pointer produces a pointer that points that many *values* earlier. So if `&a - 4` was legal, it would produce a pointer *4 `int`* earlier, which is *16 bytes* earlier given our 4 byte `int` assumption. (And it's not actually legal, since it would produce a pointer outside of the object to which the pointer originally pointed.)

So what you would need to do is cast it to a `char *`.

Pointer to 1st byte: `( (char *)&a ) + 0`
Pointer to 2nd byte: `( (char *)&a ) + 1`
Pointer to 3rd byte: `( (char *)&a ) + 2`
Pointer to 4th byte: `( (char *)&a ) + 3`

So, in your case, you'd simply want

```c
char *string = (char *)&a;
```

**Problem #3**

This makes absolutely no sense:

```c
printf("%s", string);
```

Despite the name, `string` doesn't point to a string. Not only is it not NUL-terminated, it's quite likely the representation of the integer includes NUL characters.

Comment: For problem #1 I specified that the memory is from high to low. Thank you for pointing out problem #2, it's a good way to cast it first. For problem #3, sometime char* string can define a string, e.g. char* string="Hello world!". It is a const string defined by char*. But originally char* should be pointed to an address, so I tried to give it an address.

Comment: Re "*I specified that the memory is from high to low.* Whatever you think that means makes no sense different. My answer stands. Subtracting anything makes no sense whatsoever. The bytes of `a` start at `&a`. This is *guaranteed*. The order of bytes will be different on a little endian machine compared to a big-endian machine, but they're still going to be at `( (char *)&a ) + 0` .. `( (char *)&a ) + k`, where `k` is a non-negative integer.

Comment: What you say about Problem #3 also makes no sense. You are printing the internal representation of the `int` `5`. Which 1) contains NUL, and 2) isn't NUL-temrinated. This is a major problem.

Comment: For problem#1, the address &a-4, &a-3, &a-2, &a-1, even wrong, was not the address of int a. I think you didn't understand the original question, int a's address is always &a, &a+0.25, &a+0.5 and &a+0.75..

Comment: If you mean "wasn't suppose to be the address of `int a`, then you have two other major problems, the first of which is that there are no other variables in your program.

Answer (score 1):

> The address of local variables is from high to low.

The C standard guarantees no such thing. It may or may not be true for your compiler + platform.

> ```
> char *string =  &a - 4;
> ```

Since `&a` has type `int*`, subtracting 4 from it means you shift `sizeof(int) * 4` bytes over, rather than just `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Wow, it works well when I chance "&a-4" to "&a-1"(assume the address of local variables is from high to low in my environment)!!! Thank you. But when it was "&a-4", it should point to 16 bytes below the int a in memory i.e. a char array which can store 15 charactors + "\0". Do you know why it couldn't work in this case?

Comment: @EternayLoveLyJoy: Undefined behaviour means anything is valid — you cannot expect any behaviour.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Got it, thank you. Just a little experiment haha.